# Rows not showing up in DataTable c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy data from my datagridview to a datatable so i can export to a csv file

here is the code

```
public DataTable createdatatablefromdgv()
   {
       DataTable dsptable = new DataTable();

       for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
       {
           DataColumn dspcolumn = new DataColumn(dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText);
           dsptable.Columns.Add(dspcolumn);
       }
       int noOfColumns = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
       foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView1.Rows)
       {
           DataRow dataRow = dsptable.NewRow();

           for (int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++)
           {
               dataRow[i] = dgvr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
           }

       }
       return dsptable;
   }
```

It seems like it copies the data from the the grid to to the table but when I return the datatable all there is the columns no rows

Comment: `dsptable.Rows.Add(dataRow)` isn't called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not adding dataRow to data table after assigning values to its columns.

```
public DataTable createdatatablefromdgv()
{
   DataTable dsptable = new DataTable();

   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
   {
       DataColumn dspcolumn = new DataColumn(dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText);
       dsptable.Columns.Add(dspcolumn);
   }
   int noOfColumns = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
   foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView1.Rows)
   {
       DataRow dataRow = dsptable.NewRow();

       for (int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++)
       {
           dataRow[i] = dgvr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
       }
       dsptable.Rows.Add(dataRow); //Add this statement to add rows to Data Table

   }
   return dsptable;
}
```

Comment: +1 didn't want to answer it myself, thought I was just being to simplistic with the problem and would've looked stupid :P

Comment: Wasn't me who asked question, I was just saying why I gave a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct but a little explanation as to why you encountered this problem. One would think that by calling `NewRow()` on the `DataTable` you would add a new row to the `DataTable` and then be able to access it.

What `NewRow` actually does is give you an instance of a `DataRow` which you can then use column names as apose to column identifiers (integers).

This allows you to do something like this

```
DataRow dataRow = dsptable.NewRow();
foreach(DataColumn dc in dsptable.Columns)
{
   dataRow[dc.ColumnName] = dgvr.Cells[dc.ColumnName].Value.ToString()
}
```

Alternatively you could just call `Rows.Add()` which takes an object array or a as you were trying to do a `DataRow`.

```
List<string> rowData = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++)
{
   rowData.Add(dgvr.Cells[i].Value.ToString());
}
dsptable.Rows.Add(rowData.ToArray());
```

This should explain adding rows to a datatable more simply :)